# Ansible module s3 - mode=get errors

Tags: ansible

```
- name: download files from s3 but dont download if the file checksums match
  s3: bucket=bname object=/file.gz dest=/opt/tmp/file.gz mode=get
```

Above snippet works correctly and pulls the file. gz from s3 and places it on /opt/tmp/ location

But if i am going to rerun the above task (when the file is already downloaded once and is present at /opt/tmp/), It is throwing the error -

> msg: Files uploaded with
>   multipart of s3 are not supported with checksum, unable to compute
>   checksum.

I tried to use `overwrite=different`

```
# GET an object but dont download if the file checksums match
s3: bucket=bname object=/file.gz dest=/opt/tmp/file.gz mode=get overwrite=different
```

But i am getting the error -

> msg: Boolean different not in either boolean list

---

Any workaround or suggestion on how i can make sure that i can rerun the task without worry will help, Thanks.

Comment: What version of Ansible are you using?

Comment: ansible --version 1.9.4

Answer (score 2):

```
- shell: if [[ -f "/opt/tmp/file.gz" ]]; then /bin/true; else /bin/false; fi
  register: result
  ignore_errors: True

- name: download files from s3 but dont download if the file exists
  s3: bucket=bname object=/file.gz dest=/opt/tmp/file.gz mode=get
  when: result|failed
```

Workaround - Checking the file is present or not, Skip - if the file is present and download - if it is not present.

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/5442
explains similar issue